# ASP.NET MVC Wizard, WCF and validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, validation, wizard

I have an asp.net mvc wizard with 5 steps. My business model is implemented using DDD. The architecture of the web application is something like this..
View->Controller->WCF->DDD->Repository and Database.
Business data validation is implemented in DDD, and WCF makes a call to it to validate data.

I am finding that every step in the wizard I need to call WCF(as part of server side validation)  to check if data is valid, and then return result to Controller.

Is this wrong ? Should data validation be part of  the model that lives closer to the Controller ? Is there a better solution ?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by DDD?  I always thought it meant Domain Driven Design...

Comment: It is the Domain Driven Design. In the service of DDD is where the validation is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Data Validaion should remain in  the model itself , i this way the validation logic is cetralized , and if you want to change  the change the business rules for validation , you need to change it at one place only.